# Public Scala constructor fields not public in Java

Tags: java, scala

The question is quite simple. When I declare a Scala field directly in a constructor, like this:

```
class Vector2D(val x: Float, val y: Float) {

}
```

The fields `x` and `y` are not public in Java. For example:

```
public class JavaMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector2D vec = new Vector2D(1, 2);
        System.out.println(vec.x); //Won't compile.
    }
}
```

However, in Scala this will compile:

```
object ScalaMain {
    def main(args: Array[String]) = {
        var vec = new Vector2D(1, 2);
        println(vec.x);
    }
}
```

Why does this not compile in Java? Is there a workaround or correct approach?

If you are wondering these classes are in the same project and same package. I am using [Scala IDE](http://scala-ide.org/).

Another interesting thing, is that the IDE will put a red underline under the incorrect code but fails to display an error icon next to the file with the error like it normally would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can access scala class members from java with paranthesis like `member_variable()`.

If you print the scala compiled class, you will see accessors defined as `def x()` and `def y()`.

```
$ scalac -print Vector2d.scala
[[syntax trees at end of                   cleanup]] // Vector2d.scala
package <empty> {
  class Vector2D extends Object {
    <paramaccessor> private[this] val x: Float = _;
    <stable> <accessor> <paramaccessor> def x(): Float = Vector2D.this.x;
    <paramaccessor> private[this] val y: Float = _;
    <stable> <accessor> <paramaccessor> def y(): Float = Vector2D.this.y;
    def <init>(x: Float, y: Float): Vector2D = {
      Vector2D.this.x = x;
      Vector2D.this.y = y;
      Vector2D.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

So from java code, call the accessors `x()` or `y()`.

```
public class JavaMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector2D vec = new Vector2D(1, 2);
        System.out.println(vec.x());
    }
}
```

### Also see

[Accessing Scala instance variables from Java in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4119274/432903)

Answer (score 2):

When Scala compiles this down to class files, the `x` and `y` variables are made accessible through methods of the same name.  So in Java, you would access this variable by calling `x()`.

Note that in Scala, the use of brackets when calling methods is generally optional, which is why it looks like you are accessing the variable directly.